# how can I create a Finite State Transducer?

Tags: parsing, nlp, artificial-intelligence, state-machine

I understand Finite State Transducers , for a parser to work It needs a transition table and an algorithm that work with it,so do I need to make the whole transducers then make the transition table all by hand on paper or there is another way to make it on a computer instead of hand writing it.

other way : Do I create my own Transducers with C++ and generate a transition table from it or no ?

I am sorry If my question is a bit silly or something but I can't find an answer after more than one month of search and I hope to find it here as usual.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can roll your own. Or use (f)lex, or some other DFA generating machinery.

Comment: so I can create my own finite transducer system in c++ just to generate the table from it as openFST for example , and generate the transition table from it that i will use in my algorithm right ? as i know that the table is the important thing and after i get it , the mapping of states and etc.. is not important it , it just used to get the table ??